# Python equivalent of JavaScript FindIndex?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a search function in Python that does the same as my JavaScript function. It should just check if the id of one array of objects exists in the other array of objects, if it does not exist I need to add that product to DB. However I can't seem to figure it out in Python (still learning), this is the JS version (works fine)

```
for (let i = 0, length = NewProducts.length; i < length; ++i) {
  if (Products.findIndex((o) => o.id === NewProducts[i].id) == -1){
    --- add NewProducts[i] to DB --
  }
}
```

and this is what I have for the Python equivalent:

```
i = 0
while i < len(NewProducts):
    exists = [x for x['id'] in Products if x.attr == NewProducts][i]['id']
    if exists: 
        do nothing with NewProducts[i]
    else:
        add NewProducts[i] to DB
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript, although `.findIndex` works for your purpose, you would actually use `.some` for this -- it doesn't require a comparison with -1 and just returns a boolean.

In JavaScript this would be better written as:

```js
for (let product of NewProducts) {
    if (!Products.some((o) => o.id === product.id)) {
        // add product to DB
    }
}
```

In Python this would be:

```py
for product in NewProducts:
    if not any(x['id'] == product['id'] for x in Products):
        # add product to DB
```

Answer (score 1):

Python has short-hand that you can use in this case:

```
new_products = [1, 2, 3, 6]
existing_products = [1, 3, 4, 5]

for to_add_to_db in set(new_products) - set(existing_products):
    function_to_add_to_db(to_add_to_db)
```

Essentially what this does is to create two sets and the subtraction means that only those from set `new_products` remain in the iterator that are not in `existing_products`. Mathematically speaking this is the left difference.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you need `index` function here.

```py
for product in NewProducts:
  if product in Products:
    do nothing with NewProducts[i]
  else:
    add NewProducts[i] to DB
```